# Proteus - Simulation of capacitor discharge

Tags: capacitor, simulation, proteus

Hello I am having difficulties using Proteus to make a simulation of a graph for demonstration on the graph or discharge of the capacitor. It shows the instant after unloading and there is no logarithm graphic of the unloading, I am then reproducing in the graph, precious guidance.

[image]

Comment: Set the voltage scales to match the voltage you are using, and run the sim for several times your chosen RC time constant.

Comment: If you look at the x-axis in the image of the "graph that should occur", there is no multiplier on the numbers. In the "Circuit done" part, it shows a multiplier of maybe minutes, maybe mega (1 000 000).

Comment: I am not able to do it, do you have any image or indication to execute?